# Rolling correlation two data frames

Tags: r, time-series, correlation

I have 2 data frames, **separate** ones, where I have the log daily returns of some stocks. For example:

```
Index   Date    Close    Volume  Open    High    Low    Return
1259    27/07/2015  627.26  2673801 621 634.3   620.5   NA
1258    28/07/2015  628 1713684 632.83  632.83  623.31  1.18E-03
1257    29/07/2015  631.93  1573146 628.8   633.36  622.65  6.24E-03
1256    30/07/2015  632.59  1472286 630 635.22  622.05  1.04E-03
1255    31/07/2015  625.61  1705286 631.38  632.91  625.5   -1.11E-02
```

Suppose this is df1 and the second df2 is similar. Variable of the returns have the same name (df1$Return, df2$Return)

I am trying to create a rolling correlation for example of 5 days window. I have some questions, as I am pretty new to this:

1. What is the easiest way to do that with separate data frames? I searched a bit and try to understand how to apply the rollapply but with no success. Can somebody explain how I can create the function and then apply it?

Something like:

```
corx <- function(x) cor(df1$return, df2$return)
mycors <- rollapply(c(df1$return, df2$return),5, corx)
```

2. Also I had a general question, what is the best practice of sorting the time series date, ascending or descending? I suppose this might have an effect on applying the rollapply , so I would be interested to understand.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke `rollapplyr` over the indexes like this:

```
library(zoo)

set.seed(123)

ret1 <- rnorm(10)
ret2 <- rnorm(10)

rollapplyr(seq_along(ret1), 5, function(ix) cor(ret1[ix], ret2[ix]), fill = NA)
##  [1]         NA         NA         NA         NA -0.2440453  0.6974227
##  [7]  0.7729576  0.9777006  0.8008661  0.8428961
```

or cbind the return vectors together and use `by.column = FALSE` :

```
ret <- cbind(ret1, ret2)
rollapplyr(ret, 5, function(x) cor(x[, 1], x[, 2]), by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)
##  [1]         NA         NA         NA         NA -0.2440453  0.6974227
##  [7]  0.7729576  0.9777006  0.8008661  0.8428961
```

Normally time is ascending. If you create a ts, zoo or xts time series object that is the convention used.

Comment: How though can I call in my function variables from the two different dataframes? For example I used it like this:

`rollapplyr(seq_along(df1[,1]), 5, function(x,y) cor(x,y),  df1$returns, df2$returns, fill = NA)`

But i am getting an error. Of course this applies to the first solution, without binding the variables (I'll use that if I don't manage to find a solution with the separate dataframes) Thank you for the help!

Comment: `ret1 <- df1$returns; ret2 <- df2$returns`